# Domain specific ontologies to download? Specifically for agricultural domain

Tags: ontology

I am looking for ontologies made for the domain of agriculture. I need these ontologies for testing a logic I implemented for merging domain specific ontologies. I specifically need ontologies that are created for the sub domains of agriculture(ontologies of other domains will also be useful as well).

For example: Crops ontology, Fertilizer ontology, Rice ontology, Weed ontology.

Any kind of ontology will be helpful. Does anyone know where to find such ontologies? I couldn't find any.

If anyone know ontologies like these related to a domain other than agriculture, mention them too. Thank you in advance.

Sorry if I posted a wrong kind of question.

Comment: Such a question might be on-topic on [opendata.se].

Comment: Unfortunately, resource recommendation questions such as this are off-topic for Stack Overflow. As @unor mentioned, it's worth checking out opendata.stackexchange.com, as it might fit there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state exactly what you mean by ontology, so I'm assuming a definition as is commonly used in the life-sciences, encompassing a wide degree of axiomatization with hundreds to potentially hundreds of thousands of classes. If you mean something more like an RDF schema then my examples may not apply.

[AgroPortal](http://agroportal.lirmm.fr/) has over 100 ontologies/thesauri in the domain of or closely related to Agriculture. You can see in the top 5 accessed ontologies some of the most relevant ones, including AGROVOC. Note that GACS is itself a merger of other thesauri, so if your goal is to test a merge framework you may want to hold this one back. Many of these are more thesaurus-like, but some such as ENVO and AGRO employ more extensive OWL axiomatization.

Note also that considerable work has been done in the [Planteome](http://planteome.org) project to merge together different crop ontologies into a pan-species trait ontology, this may also be useful for your evaluation.

If you are interested in applying your techniques more broadly in the life sciences, common sub-domains are anatomy, phenotype and disease. These frequently are used as tests in initiatives like the [Ontology Alignment Evaluation Initiative](http://oaei.ontologymatching.org/). Although it sounds like your technique goes beyond mapping and into merging, it may be useful to look at past competitions. I have also produced merged [anatomy](http://doi.org/10.1186/2041-1480-5-21), [disease](http://doi.org/10.1101/048843) and [phenotype](http://doi.org/10.3410/f1000research.2-30.v) ontologies, these have all been curated and could be used as test sets for your approach.

Comment: Please don't answer such off-topic questions. Offsite resource recommendation questions are expressly off-topic for Stack Overflow.